# Debug Builds Work, Release Build fails - llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, compilation

Since upgrading to Lion (and downgrading to Xcode 4.1 from the beta) I can't compile release builds of one of my projects anymore.

- I was able to compile on 4.1 with this same project (and no changes) prior to all of my upgrading and downgrading.
- I can still compile and run in the simulator
- I've deleted the entire derived data folder for the project to no avail
- I've been Googling for days with no success

Any Ideas? Thanks for any help you can give. If I need to post more info, let me know.

```
Ld /Users/jhudnall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MethodApps-abncbxegxjzxtgadrrvoorkhofeu/Build/Intermediates/MethodApps.build/Debug-iphoneos/PLSD.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PLSD normal armv6
cd /Users/jhudnall/Documents/MethodApps/MethodAppsBuilds/1213-PLSD/methodapps
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/jhudnall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MethodApps-abncbxegxjzxtgadrrvoorkhofeu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/jhudnall/Documents/MethodApps/MethodAppsBuilds/1213-PLSD/methodapps/MethodApps/Classes/MASharing/Sharers/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine -L/Users/jhudnall/Documents/MethodApps/MethodAppsBuilds/1213-PLSD/methodapps -F/Users/jhudnall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MethodApps-abncbxegxjzxtgadrrvoorkhofeu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/jhudnall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MethodApps-abncbxegxjzxtgadrrvoorkhofeu/Build/Intermediates/MethodApps.build/Debug-iphoneos/PLSD.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PLSD.LinkFileList -dead_strip /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework MapKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lOAuth -lxml2.2 -o /Users/jhudnall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MethodApps-abncbxegxjzxtgadrrvoorkhofeu/Build/Intermediates/MethodApps.build/Debug-iphoneos/PLSD.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PLSD

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but for the sake of not leaving the question open, recreating the project and reimporting the files fixed it. Must've been some errant line in the build setting somewhere, even though I looked those over probably a dozen times.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit or a corny answer, but when you did the downgrade, did you remove the beta completely, reboot, then install the 4.1 version?

Comment: I didn't. I suppose that's worth a shot. I can build other projects (and successfully submit them) without issue, though.